# Error when importing dump on Plesk microsoft sql server 2018

Tags: sql-server, plesk

ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: 'TAPE'.

program 'mysql' finished with non-zero exit code: 1

The server is a MariaDB server and I keep getting this error off of uploading the .bak file I created from microsoft sql server 2018.

Please help

Comment: This question needs some editing: is it MySQL, MariaDB or SQL Server? Those are all different SQL database products.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am using Microsoft SQL server 2018 and I am trying to host a SQL server database on a MariaDB server ... is this possible?

Comment: I also faced this issue of importing MS SQL 2018 .bak then I tried SQL 2008 .bak it worked for me.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 - take your pick